# Adjusting Style based on Column in CARTO?

Tags: carto, style

An older version of CARTO allowed for adjustment of the styles based on a Column.  For example, I could show elevation points over a certain elevation as green and points under a certain elevation as red.  I can't seem to find where this is now.

Can someone help here?

Answer (score 1):

You still can do that in BUILDER, new CARTO web application. As explained [here](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/style-by-value), you have to follow these steps:

1. Click on the layer card.
2. Select the `STYLE` tab.
3. Click the `FILL` color to open the color properties for the map layer. The `SOLID` tab opens by default.
4. Click `BY VALUE` to select the column. Then you can choose the number of breaks, the color scheme, and breaking method.

[image: style by value]
<sub>(source: [carto.com](https://carto.com/learn/img/guides/style-by-value/color-by-value.png))</sub>

Finally, I highly recommend having a look at a these related blog posts, about [styling with Turbo CARTO](https://carto.com/blog/styling-with-turbo-carto) (the CartoCSS preprocessor behind the STYLE UI) and [the new CARTOColors](https://carto.com/blog/introducing-cartocolors).